# Updating directive from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that displays a list retrieved from a Service, which uses a factory. The main controller updates the id which is used by the Service to get the required list. I need to update the directive when this happens and can't seem to get it working, maybe I'm using the wrong approach. Here's my code:

```
Chat.service('SubscriberService', ['User', function(User){
    this.subscribers = [];
    this.id = -1;

    this.updateSubscriberList = function(id){
        console.log("fetching data");
        this.id = id
        this.subscribers = User.fetch({ id: this.id });
    }

    this.getSubscribers = function(){
        return this.subscribers;
    }
    return this;
}]);

Chat.directive('subscribersList', function(SubscriberService){
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateURL: 'angular/templates/subscribers_list.html',
      controller: function($scope){

        $scope.subscribers = SubscriberService.getSubscribers();

          $scope.$watch('subscribers', function(value){

            console.log("watch triggered");
            $scope.subscribers = SubscriberService.getSubscribers();    

          });
      }
  }
});

Chat.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, SubscriberService){
    var id = $stateParams.id;

    //update the current id when the URL changes
    SubscriberService.updateSubscriberList(id);

});
```

Any ideas? I need MainCtrl to update the id in the service, and when the service fetches new info, the directive update the view.

Thanks.

Comment: `this.subscribers = User.fetch({ id: this.id });` looks very suspect to me, shouldn't User.fetch be returning a promise?

Comment: Yes but when the promise resolves you get the array? @KevinB

Comment: `SubscriberService.updateSubscriberList` when called does **not** change the reference assigned in: `$scope.subscribers = SubscriberService.getSubscribers();`. A couple of options available here. The easiest (but imho the least elegant) would be to use an intermediate object e.g. `data.subscribers`.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

As artur grzesiak pointed out in the comments, the value of `$scope.subscribers` is never updated. Instead the variable `this.subscribers` is set to a new value in the service, meaning they contain different objects.

Instead you could use this service:

```
Chat.service('SubscriberService', ['User', function(User){
    this.subscribers = [];
    this.id = -1;
    var self = this;

    this.updateSubscriberList = function(id){
        console.log("fetching data");
        this.id = id
        User.fetch({ id: id }, function(result) {
            // Removed the original data and replaces it with the result.
            // This keeps the reference to the original object the same.
            // Use self, because I'm not sure where `this` refers to in this context.
            angular.copy(result, self.subscribers);
        });
    };

    this.getSubscribers = function(){
        return this.subscribers;
    };
    return this;
}]);
```

Comment: This is not triggering the $watch function, any ideas?

Comment: Try using $watchCollection instead of $watch.